# PHPExcel can't show currency symbol

Tags: php, phpexcel, string-formatting

I was asked to edit a file which is using the deprecated PHPExcel library.. I'm not allowed to update to PHPSpreadSheet so I need to sort this out using PHPExcel.
I'm trying to show the currency symbol with the following code:

```
$activeSheet->getStyle($col.$row)
            ->getNumberFormat()
            ->setFormatCode('_("$"* #,##0.00_);_("$"* \(#,##0.00\);_("$"* "-"??_);_(@_)');
```

I also tried with the format code `€ ####0,00` and `€ ##,##0.00` with no luck..

The weird behaviour happens when I open the file, I click on the cell and hit return key without making any change, then the currency symbol is displayed correctly. How can I get this to work without any manual intervention?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried escaping the currency symbol, such as `\$`?

Comment: Yes, nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem was given by the decimals and thousands separator, which were mismatching from the used format code.

```
$price = number_format( $raw_price, 2, ".", "");
$activeSheet->setCellValue("G$row", $price)
$activeSheet->getStyle("G$row")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode( '"€" ###0,00_-' );
```

I just had to edit as follows:

```
$price = number_format( $raw_price, 2, ",", "");
```

Comment: You should not format the numeric value in any way at all.... using `number_format()` creates a string, and the format code you are setting only applies to integer and float values

Answer (score 0):

According to the [this PHPExcel example](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/dcc18322155aed681bc7b1c15d9fb055ee7c8afb/samples/templates/sampleSpreadsheet.php#L121), you can use pre-defined constants:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle('E4:E13')
            ->getNumberFormat()
            ->setFormatCode(NumberFormat::FORMAT_CURRENCY_USD_SIMPLE);

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle('E4:E13')
            ->getNumberFormat()
            ->setFormatCode(NumberFormat::FORMAT_CURRENCY_EUR_SIMPLE);
```

These constants are defined in [PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat](http://oweb1.osakac.ac.jp/labs/koeda/tmp/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Style/PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat.html#constFORMAT_CURRENCY_EUR_SIMPLE):

```
const FORMAT_CURRENCY_USD_SIMPLE        = '"$"#,##0.00_-';
const FORMAT_CURRENCY_USD               = '$#,##0_-';
const FORMAT_CURRENCY_EUR_SIMPLE        = '[$EUR ]#,##0.00_-';
```

Or you can define your own, but be aware that these must be compliant to Excel cell formats.

Provide the cell value as a simple floating point number then, with no currency symbol or thousand's separator.

Comment: The link/example you posted is from PHPSpreadsheet.. PHPExcel class would be `PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat`. Not a big issue anyway, still not working..

Answer (score -1):

```
// Only for money format. For Eg. 11,000.00
 $object->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle("D4:S12")
            ->getNumberFormat()
            ->setFormatCode('#,##0.00_-');
```